# Lighter version of Fira Math

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex, beamer-metropolis

I have making a Metropolis beamer and came across Fira Math font. Everything compiles, but the math expressions are heavier than the regular text. I checked the accompanying demo file and noticed that the author uses `\mathversion{Thin}` command. For some reason, it won't work in my code.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

\usetheme[titleformat=smallcaps,block=fill]{metropolis}
%\metroset{outer/frametitleformat=smallcaps}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame}
%\mathversion{Thin}
The formula
$z = d - \kappa x = (1 - \kappa\xi) d = \zeta d$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Fira font (sans) and Fira Math from the MikTeX console.  There are numerous weights available  for the text .

*For Fire Math I found only one: Regular.*

The closest weight for text so far is book, but ... keep reading.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex 

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} 
\usepackage{FiraSans}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}    
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math Regular}

\usetheme[titleformat=smallcaps,block=fill]{metropolis}
%\metroset{outer/frametitleformat=smallcaps}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded] 

\begin{document}
        
\begin{frame}{Frame}
        
\textsf{The formula (regular)}

{\firalight The formula (light)}

{\firathin The formula(thin)}

$z = d - \kappa x = (1 - \kappa\xi) d = \zeta d$

{\firabook  The formula closest (book)}

{\firamedium Other formula (medium)}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I found that the regular weight comes up as light!  So perhaps this is the heaviness  you notice in the math fonts.

[image: one]

At this time I do not know how  the theme metropolis is handling this font but it looks that uses `Fira Sans Light` as the regular weight.
For example using   `\usetheme[titleformat=smallcaps,block=fill]{Dresden}` the regular font comes out alright. Also there are less space between lines.

[image: F]

**UPDATE**

This setup will produce light weight text and formulas, like is shown in the demo for the `metropolis` theme.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex 

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} 
\usepackage{FiraSans}

%   \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}    % do not use
%   \usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math} % do not use

\usetheme[titleformat=smallcaps,block=fill]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded] 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame}

    The formula 
    
    $z = d - \kappa x = (1 - \kappa\xi) d = \zeta d$    
    
    
    \begin{equation*}
    e = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n
    \end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: fin]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I think I will use a heavier font for the text instead. The last solution is nice, but I use a lot of Greek and mathbb characters, so they will be visibly different :(